# Can you stop a task when using aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task

How to stop and start a long running `Task` from an aspx page? I know how to stop a task with `CancellationTokenSource` in C#. In a windows form and a console app. But cannot seem to get it work on an aspx page. Is it even possible? I'm pretty sure because the page is posting the UI thread is lost.  Below is an example of a windows form project.

```
private async void btnGetDataAwait_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   try
   {
      btnGetDataAwait.Enabled = false;
      List<Person> people = await repo.Get(tokenSource.Token);
      foreach (var person in people)
      {
         listBox1.Items.Add(person);
      }
      btnGetDataAwait.Enabled = true;
   } 
   catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TASK CANCELED");
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "EXCEPTION");
   }
}
```

If your task was in an endless loop, on purpose, how can you grab the same thread/task and stop it?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms? I'm guessing it's. NET Framework and not Core? Is that correct?

Comment: @Flydog57 .. right .. i can't seem to stop the thread/task using aspx pages.

Comment: When you talk about a long running task, are you talking about a task that serves a specific web request, or a task that runs independently of any web request?

Comment: There is no "UI thread" in ASP.NET. WebForms has only a superficial similarity to WinForms. The synchronziation-context in ASP.NET is because (with a few exceptions) the thread that created the request's `HttpContext` needs to be the thread that completes the request.

Comment: No need for a web request.  The long running task could be write to a file every 5 secs.  Store on server.  @TheodorZoulias

Comment: But that's not the code you show. It's hard for us to imagine what you are talking about.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There's also tasks that you start from a HTTP request but are completed afterwards (e.g. using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`).

Comment: "If your task was in an endless loop, on purpose, how can you grab the same thread/task and stop it?" - **never use the `Thread` class!** - use the `Task` class and `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` feature in ASP.NET (or `IApplicationLifetime` and `IHostedService` in ASP.NET Core). And **NEVER EVER KILL/ABORT/STOP A THREAD!** - this is because IIS and ASP.NET manage their own thread pools - if you kill a thread you'll destabilize your entire web-server process.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). Quote: *QueueBackgroundWorkItem will register the work with ASP.NET. When ASP.NET has to recycle, it will notify the background work (by setting a CancellationToken) and will then wait up to 30 seconds for the work to complete.*